# pybind11: send MPI communicator from Python to CPP

Tags: python, c++, mpi, pybind11

I have a C++ class which I intend to call from python's mpi4py interface such that each node spawns the class. On the C++ side, I'm using the [Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) library (installed via [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/open-mpi)) and [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).

The C++ class is as follows:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>
// #define PyMPI_HAVE_MPI_Message 1
// #include <mpi4py/mpi4py.h>


namespace py = pybind11;

class SomeComputation
{
    float multiplier;
    std::vector<int> test;
    MPI_Comm comm_;

public:
    void Init()
    {
        int rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm_, &rank);
        test.clear();
        test.resize(10, rank);
    }

    void set_comm(MPI_Comm comm){
        this->comm_ = comm;
    }

    SomeComputation(float multiplier_) : multiplier(multiplier_){}
    ~SomeComputation() { std::cout << "Destructor Called!\n"; }


    float compute(float input)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((int)input * 10));
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << test[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return multiplier * input;
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(module_name, handle)
{
    py::class_<SomeComputation>(handle, "Cpp_computation")
        .def(py::init<float>()) // args of constructers are template args
        .def("set_comm", &SomeComputation::set_comm)  
        .def("compute", &SomeComputation::compute)
        .def("cpp_init", &SomeComputation::Init);
}
```

and here's the python interface spawning the same C++:

```py
from build.module_name import * 
import time

from mpi4py import MPI


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()


m = Cpp_computation(44.0) # send communicator to cpp
m.cpp_init()
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(m.compute(i))
    time.sleep(1)
    i+=1
```

I've already tried "[Sharing an MPI communicator using pybind11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52657173/4593199)" but I'm stuck at a long unhelpful error ([full message](https://pastebin.com/raw/zfEJGh27)):

```
[...]
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1398:22:   required from 'pybind11::class_<type_, options>& pybind11::class_<type_, options>::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...) [with Func = void (SomeComputation::*)(ompi_communicator_t*); Extra = {}; type_ = SomeComputation; options = {}]'
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:79:7:   required from here
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/type_traits:1372:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct ompi_communicator_t'
 1372 |     : public integral_constant<bool, __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)>
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:6:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/4.1.2/include/mpi.h:419:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct ompi_communicator_t'
  419 | typedef struct ompi_communicator_t *MPI_Comm;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[...]

/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1398:22:   required from 'pybind11::class_<type_, options>& pybind11::class_<type_, options>::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...) [with Func = void (SomeComputation::*)(ompi_communicator_t*); Extra = {}; type_ = SomeComputation; options = {}]'
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:79:7:   required from here
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/descr.h:40:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct ompi_communicator_t'
   40 |         return {{&typeid(Ts)..., nullptr}};
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:6:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/4.1.2/include/mpi.h:419:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct ompi_communicator_t'
  419 | typedef struct ompi_communicator_t *MPI_Comm;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[...]

                 from /Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:1:
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/descr.h:40:42: error: could not convert '{{<expression error>, nullptr}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::array<const std::type_info*, 3>'
   40 |         return {{&typeid(Ts)..., nullptr}};
      |                                          ^
      |                                          |
      |                                          <brace-enclosed initializer list>

[...]

In file included from /Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:1:
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h: In instantiation of 'void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize(Func&&, Return (*)(Args ...), const Extra& ...) [with Func = pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<void, SomeComputation, ompi_communicator_t*, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling>(void (SomeComputation::*)(ompi_communicator_t*), const pybind11::name&, const pybind11::is_method&, const pybind11::sibling&)::<lambda(SomeComputation*, ompi_communicator_t*)>; Return = void; Args = {SomeComputation*, ompi_communicator_t*}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling}]':
[..]
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1398:22:   required from 'pybind11::class_<type_, options>& pybind11::class_<type_, options>::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...) [with Func = void (SomeComputation::*)(ompi_communicator_t*); Extra = {}; type_ = SomeComputation; options = {}]'
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/main.cpp:79:7:   required from here
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:266:73:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'pybind11::detail::descr<18, SomeComputation, ompi_communicator_t>::types()'
/Users/purusharth/Documents/hiwi/pympicontroller/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:266:39: error: 'constexpr' call flows off the end of the function
  266 |         PYBIND11_DESCR_CONSTEXPR auto types = decltype(signature)::types();
      |                                       ^~~~~
```

The error points to `.def("set_comm", &SomeComputation::set_comm)`

What is the cause of these errors, and how should they be resolved?

UPDATE: Added answer below by using custom type caster as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259704/pybind11-possible-to-use-mpi4py). But is it the *only* way to go about it?

Comment: From what I could decipher, MPI_comm has only been declared and not defined, so you should hold it by (`MPI_comm* comm_;`) and not directly by value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice

Comment: Of course, that might not be the real problem. Could you try and post the full main.cpp in this case? The error references line 79 but your code is shorter than this.

Comment: Is is possible you haven't imported all the required headers from MPI? A couple of the errors are referencing a type that's incomplete, so it's possible you're missing an include that is required which would "complete" the type definition.

Comment: All information should be added to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not just [linked to](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). For one thing, external pages go away (there are plenty of questions on SO where the OP didn't expect this to happen, yet it did). In the case of a long error (such as C++ compilation output), the core error messages could be posted, with a link used for the full output.

Comment: (If not sure how to edit down a long error message, assistance could be requested in chat, which requires only 20 rep, or a comment could be made to the same point.)

Comment: @jlucier afaik, i included all the required headers for mpi, infact, if i remove the setter for mpi communicator, the compilation happens without any error.

Comment: @unddoch I had stripped down some comments before pasting the code,  line 79 originally points to `set_comm` definition. (question updated)

Comment: @Jarwin: if Open MPI isn't a requirement, you might try [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/); the sample compiled without the error when I built against it.

Comment: `struct ompi_communicator_t` looks to be declared in "open-mpi/4.1.2/include/ompi/communicator/communicator.h". What happens if `#include <ompi/communicator/communicator.h>` is added to the C++ class definition file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449190/4593199

I was able to transfer MPI Communicator by creating custom MPI type caster.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <mpi4py/mpi4py.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct mpi4py_comm {
  mpi4py_comm() = default;
  mpi4py_comm(MPI_Comm value) : value(value) {}
  operator MPI_Comm () { return value; }

  MPI_Comm value;
};


namespace pybind11 { namespace detail {
  template <> struct type_caster<mpi4py_comm> {
    public:
      PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(mpi4py_comm, _("mpi4py_comm"));

      // Python -> C++
      bool load(handle src, bool) {
        PyObject *py_src = src.ptr();

        // Check that we have been passed an mpi4py communicator
        if (PyObject_TypeCheck(py_src, &PyMPIComm_Type)) {
          // Convert to regular MPI communicator
          value.value = *PyMPIComm_Get(py_src);
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        return !PyErr_Occurred();
      }

      // C++ -> Python
      static handle cast(mpi4py_comm src,
                         return_value_policy /* policy */,
                         handle /* parent */)
      {
        // Create an mpi4py handle
        return PyMPIComm_New(src.value);
      }
  };
}} // namespace pybind11::detail


// recieve a communicator and check if it equals MPI_COMM_WORLD
void print_comm(mpi4py_comm comm)
{
        int rank;
        std::vector<int> test; 
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

        test.clear();
        test.resize(10, rank); 

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << test[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
}


class SomeComputation
{
    float multiplier;
    std::vector<int> test;
    MPI_Comm comm_;

public:
    void Init()
    {
        int rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm_, &rank);
        test.clear();
        test.resize(10, rank);
    }
    SomeComputation(float multiplier_) : multiplier(multiplier_){}
    ~SomeComputation() { std::cout << "Destructor Called!\n"; }

    void set_comm(mpi4py_comm comm){
        this->comm_ = comm;
    }

    float compute(float input)
    {
        // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((int)input * 10));
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << test[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return multiplier * input;
    }
};


mpi4py_comm get_comm()
{
  return MPI_COMM_WORLD; // Just return MPI_COMM_WORLD for demonstration
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(native, m)
{
  // import the mpi4py API
  if (import_mpi4py() < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not load mpi4py API.");
  }

  // register the test functions
  m.def("print_comm", &print_comm, "Do something with the mpi4py communicator.");
  m.def("get_comm", &get_comm, "Return some communicator.");


    py::class_<SomeComputation>(m, "Cpp_computation")
        .def(py::init<float>()) // args of constructers are template args
        .def("set_comm", &SomeComputation::set_comm)
        .def("compute", &SomeComputation::compute)
        .def("cpp_init", &SomeComputation::Init);
}
```

This compiled and ran successfully, however, is there a more elegant way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `void *` as an argument compiled successfully for me. It's ABI-compatible with the pybind11 interfaces (an `MPI_Comm` is a pointer in any case). All I had to change was this:

```
void set_comm(void* comm){
  this->comm_ = (MPI_Comm)comm;
}
```

I also added MPI libraries and include folders to `setup.py`, as follows (replace folders as necessary with your MPI implementation):

```py
ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("module_name",
        ["src/main.cpp"],
        include_dirs=["/etc/alternatives/mpi-x86_64-linux-gnu"],
        library_dirs=["/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib"],
        libraries=["mpi", "mpi_cxx"],
    ),
]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. However, I get an error message stating `MPI_Comm_rank` is undefined during runtime. 
`ImportError: build/mpi_lib.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: MPI_Comm_rank`

Comment: Did you compile it with `mpicc`? I used the following command line: `CC=mpicxx CXX=mpicxx python setup.py develop`

Comment: Despite compiling it with mpicc it crashes with the same error when called from python. Could you upload your CMake file? I am not sure about `setup.py`

Comment: I'm not using CMake, all the build instructions are in setup.py. I also managed to remove the requirement to compile with mpicxx by adding the libraries directly. See edited answer. I compiled this with `python setup.py develop`. Let me know if you need more components. Adding `mpi_cxx` to the libraries fixes the above ImportError.